# jquery - split and count characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I'm trying to split a string based on a particular character and then count the number of characters within each part.  Is there a way to do this?

So, I have:

#### html

```
<a href="#" class="splitMe" title="Testing | this out">blah</a>
```

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.splitMe').each(function() {
      var item = $(this).attr('title');
      var characters = item.split("|");

      // Here's where I get stuck... 
      // Tried various methods of length, but haven't been able to get it to work

      // Most recent version that failed miserably... 
      var first = characters[0].text().length;
      var second = characters[1].text().length;

      alert(first+" "+second); //Yields characters[0] is not a function
   });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have too much jQuery in your mind:

```
var first = characters[0].length;
var second = characters[1].length;
```

`characters` is an array of *strings*, not jQuery objects. Strings don't have a `.text()` method, they are already text. Just access their `length` property.